# How to do a 'composite' select using LINQ?

Tags: xml, linq, select

I have an XML file with element Product that contains Name and Price in $. I want to select both Name and $Price but I want to add in a field for Price in Euro which I calculate. How do I do this? Thanks.

My current query is:

```
var queryAllProducts = from product in products
                    select product;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `product` has fields `Name` and `PriceUsd`, and that you also have a function called `UsdToEuro`, you can do your select as follows:

```
var queryAllProducts = from product in products
    select new {
        product.Name
    ,   product.PriceUsd
    ,   PriceEuro = UsdToEuro(product.PriceUsd)
    };
```

If you do not want to "break out" the individual fields of the product, you can bring it through the anonymous type in its entirety:

```
var queryAllProducts = from product in products
    select new {
        Product = product
    ,   PriceEuro = UsdToEuro(product.PriceUsd)
    };
```

You would access product fields as `element.Product.Name`, not as `element.Name` from the first example.

Comment: Thanks so much! This will work. But I wonder if there is a shorthand way to handle element Product if it has say 100 subelements instead of just 2 Name and PriceUsd. I prefer not to have to spell out each subelement.

Comment: @user763554 Sure, you can easily do that. I updated the answer to include this alternative.

Answer (score 1):

One way to add in the price is to return an anonymous type from your LINQ query:

```
var queryAllProducts = from product in products
                       select new { 
                           Name = product.Name,
                           Price = product.Price,
                           PriceEuro = ConvertToEuroPrice(product.Price) 
                       };
```

Another way to add a property, if the `Product` class is defined as a `partial` class, is to just add a `PriceEuro` property to that class.

```
public partial class Product
{
    public decimal PriceEuro
    {
        get { return ConvertToEuroPrice(Price); }
    }
}
```